# I have two modals on a page but only the second one closes if clicked outside of the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using w3's css modal class to make 2 modals. It works fine but one modal won't close when clicked outside the actual modal window while the other one works just fine. I'm kind of confused as they were both working just fine but something I must have done has broken the first one. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="w3-modal" id="create-store-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-round" style="width: 800px;">
    <header class="w3-container w3-theme-gradient">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('create-store-modal').style.display = 'none'" class="w3-button w3-theme-gradient w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h2 class="w3-center">Create Your Store</h2>
    </header>

    <br><br>
    <div class="w3-container">
            <form method="post" id="create-store-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="store-name">Store Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="store-name" name="store-name">
                <br>
                <label for="store-desc">Store Description </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="store-desc" name="store-description">
                <br>
                <label for="store-category">Store Category</label>
                <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-round-large" id="store-category" name="store-categoery">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($this->categories as $value):
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>"><?php echo $value['type']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <p class="w3-right-align">
                         <button class="btn">Upload Image For Store</button>
                         <input type="file" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="store-image" name="store-image">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="w3-button w3-round-large w3-theme-gradient">Create Store</button>
            </form>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <footer class="w3-container w3-theme-gradient">&nbsp;
           <p id="message"></p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var store_name = $("#store-name").val();
            var store_desc = $("#store-desc").val();
            var store_cat = $("#store-category").val();


            var formData = new FormData();

            if (document.getElementById('store-image') == null) {
                formData.append("store-name", store_name);
                formData.append("store-desc", store_desc);
                formData.append("store-cat", store_cat);
            } else {
                formData.append("store-name", store_name);
                formData.append("store-desc", store_desc);
                formData.append("store-cat", store_cat);
                formData.append("store-image", document.getElementById('store-image').files[0]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType : false,
                processData: false,
                url: "/user/make-store",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData
            }).done(function(msg) {
                $('#store-name').val("");
                $('#store-desc').val("");
                $('#message').html("<h2 class=\"w3-center\">" + msg.success + "</h2>");
            }).fail(function(msg) {
                $('#message').html("<h2 class=\"w3-center\">" + msg.failure + "</h2>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('create-store-modal');

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    var modal2 = document.getElementById('modify-store-modal');

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal2) {
            modal2.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

The other modal is identical in terms of style and classes, it just has a different id (modify-store-modal) instead of create-store-modal. Here is a link to some screenshots I took that may better explain what I am trying to say.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKtpB.jpg

Basically I am confused on why the first one won't close when clicked outside the modal while the second one works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a function to an `onclick` attribute, the earlier `onclick` method assigned (if any) will be **removed**.

```js
window.onclick = () => console.log('foo');
window.onclick = () => console.log('bar');
```

`onclick` is actually a *getter/setter*, which can hold, at most, only one click handler at a time. Your older `onclick` handler is being removed when the newer `onclick` handler is being added.

Use `addEventListener` instead, which does not have such a limitation:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // ...
```

You can also put the logic into a single handler:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('create-store-modal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('modify-store-modal');
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target === modal || event.target === modal2) {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm, that now works on the first one but the second one is broken now :/

Comment: nevermind, I had it before the second modal. Thanks! works perfectly.